# How to write a function as a mapping that is composed of another function?

Tags: functions, notation, neural-networks

Consider the following functions $f$ and $g$ where $f: X \rightarrow Y$ and $g:Y \rightarrow Z$. Here, $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ may be sets of real numbers or real vectors, but I think that is irrelevant to the question.

I want to write this as single mapping $h$ where the output of $f$ is the input to $g$ (i.e., $f$ is composed of $g$). What would be the best notation for this?

For context, these functions represent a sequence of neural networks.

Comment: Well... $f$ composed with $g$ is conmonlly writen $f \circ g$.

Comment: @BrianBritosSimmari Did you not mean $g\circ f$ here?

Comment: @drhab You are right.

Comment: @drhab yes, I meant $g \circ f$. I could write $g \circ f: X \rightarrow Z$. Maybe, that is enough?

Comment: @Ralff Yes, that is enough.